# J2me: Lwuit Display Size 176x220

Tags: java-me, resize, lwuit

I create app for J2ME with LWUIT library.

I checked on 240x320 display size phones it works beautiful
and then checked on 176x220 that shows badly theme.

I think this happen is for  Margin Style that I used in codes and theme.

How can I create a project with 176x220 size or bigger than 240x320?

I found `Display.DENSITY_VERY_LOW` but how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the margin in millimeters instead of pixels in the designer tool.